how to link a python code with an excel preadsheet using a barcode scanner to input student data into the excel sheet?
I need to create code that I will use in pycharm to link an excel spreadsheet and I need to input student data into that excel spreadsheet using a barcode scanner to scan students barcodes. Also, I need to generate barcodes in excel spreadsheet itself which I already have done. But I would like to know if I will be able to use those barcodes that I generated in excel and scann those barcodes to input the student data in the excel sheet itself. The barcodes only hold the students Last name and first name. But the excel sheet has to have the following headings: Student Barcode ID, Student Name, Did the student attend last month? and for this part of the code it's gotta say if the student attended last month "yes or no. depending if the student attended or not. Another part of the code gotta say "Total attendance days" and the spreadsheet has to sum up the total days the student attended for the last month. The last part of the code has to say day one, day two, day three, day four etc. for every day of the current month. Each day of the month in the excel sheet has to match with every day of the month like for example Monday April 1st, Tuesda 2nd etc. and to check for attendance if the student attended every day of the week or month there has to be a number 1 for every day that particular student attended school under the day attended either if is Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday etc.
import datetime
import openpyxl

# Function to update attendance in Excel sheet
def update_attendance(student_name, attendance_status):
  today = datetime.datetime.now()
  month = today.strftime("%B")
  year = today.year
  date = today.strftime("%B %d")

  # Open the Excel file
  wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('attendance.xlsx')
  sheet = wb.active

  # Find the column for today's date
  col = 0
  for i in range(1, sheet.max_column + 1):
     if sheet.cell(row=1, column=i).value == date:
      col = i
      break

  # If today's date column not found, add it
  if col == 0:
    col = sheet.max_column + 1
    sheet.cell(row=1, column=col).value = date

  # Find the row for the student
  row = 0
  for i in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    if sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value == student_name:
      row = i
      break

  # If student not found, add a new row
  if row == 0:
   row = sheet.max_row + 1
   sheet.cell(row=row, column=1).value = student_name

  # Update attendance
  sheet.cell(row=row, column=col).value = attendance_status

  # Save the workbook
  wb.save('attendance.xlsx')

  # Example usage
  student_barcode = input("Scan student barcode: ")
  # Assuming the barcode contains student name and attendance status (e.g., "John Doe 1")
  student_name, attendance_status = student_barcode.split()

  update_attendance(student_name, attendance_status)

  # This is the code that I came up with but I haven't tried yet because I don't know if it is right        or not. I want to make sure that the code is the right one before I can test it out. 


Do you want everything python-ised or are you open to add some formula in your attendance.xlsx sheet to get "Total attendance days"?

In excel, you can put "Student Name" in columnA, "Total Attendence Days" in column B, and dates in Column C, Column D.... then in Column B, say B2, you just need to input a formula =SUM(C2:Q2) to calculate "Total Attendence Days". but if you want to do it in python, you will need to add a global variable ATTENDANCE_INFOS_BY_STUDENT_NAME = {}, where key of dictionary is student name, value is a tuple for date and attendance status, and update that dictionary in your update_attendance function.

I am open to add some formula in my attendance.xlsx sheet

In that case, your current codes does exactly what it is supposed to do.  Except that student_name, attendance_status = student_barcode.split() won't work for "John Doe 1", because there is a space between first name and last name.

Here is how you can set up your 'attendance.xlsx':
Column Headers and Dates are in row2.
Student names and attendance data starts from row3.
In column B: use =SUM(D3:AH3), drag down the formula. (I assume you will only input 1 months data in this sheet? if not, you can add some excel formulas to check latest months)
In column C: use =B3>0, drag down the formula.

Now since you have formulas and headers in your 'attendance.xlsx', max_row and max_column won't work.
so I updated your update_attendance a little bit:
import datetime
import openpyxl

FILE_NAME = 'attendance.xlsx'

ATTENDANCE_DATA_START_ROW = 3
ATTENDANCE_DATA_START_COL = 4


# Function to update attendance in Excel sheet
def update_attendance(student_name, attendance_status):
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    month = today.strftime("%B")
    year = today.year
    date = today.strftime("%B %d")

    # Open the Excel file
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=FILE_NAME)
    sheet = wb.active

    # Find the column for today's date
    col = ATTENDANCE_DATA_START_COL - 1
    used_col = ATTENDANCE_DATA_START_COL - 1
    for i in range(ATTENDANCE_DATA_START_COL, sheet.max_column + 1):
        value = sheet.cell(row=ATTENDANCE_DATA_START_ROW - 1, column=i).value
        if value == date:
            col = i
            break
        if value is not None:
            used_col = i

    # If today's date column not found, add it
    if col == ATTENDANCE_DATA_START_COL - 1:
        col = used_col + 1
        sheet.cell(row=ATTENDANCE_DATA_START_ROW - 1, column=col).value = date

    # Find the row for the student
    row = ATTENDANCE_DATA_START_ROW - 1
    used_row = ATTENDANCE_DATA_START_ROW - 1
    for i in range(ATTENDANCE_DATA_START_ROW, sheet.max_row + 1):
        value = sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value
        if value == student_name:
            row = i
            break
        if value is not None:
            used_row = i

    # If student not found, add a new row
    if row == ATTENDANCE_DATA_START_ROW - 1:
        row = used_row + 1
        sheet.cell(row=row, column=1).value = student_name

    # Update attendance
    sheet.cell(row=row, column=col).value = int(attendance_status)

    # Save the workbook
    wb.save(FILE_NAME)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Example usage
    student_barcode = input("Scan student barcode: ")
    # Assuming the barcode contains student name and attendance status (e.g., "JohnDoe 1")
    student_name, attendance_status = student_barcode.split()

    update_attendance(student_name, attendance_status)

